# Masking IP on the Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am attempting to provide some anonymity to my users on the Windows Phone when they post data to my server.

Without going into to much detail, the only thing that ties the user to the data in my database is the ip they call into my server from. I would like to mask this.

I have looked into creating a `WebProxy` object but apparently this isn't available in the Windows Phone .NET framework.

I am considering just informing the user of their exposure and making it easy for them to setup a VPN on their device.

Is there another way I can mask their IP when they call into my server? The more automated I can make it for them the better.

Comment: So you assume users trust your app, but don't trust your server??? I'm not sure what forces you to log user's IP and preserve logs on server.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on this but I am almost positive that the US Government requires me to keep a log of all internet traffic through my server. So, since that's the case I will just mask my users IP before it gets to me. Then the Gov. can go F themselves

Comment: I am almost 100% certain that that is wrong.  Http logs can grow very large very quickly.  The storage requirements for an active site to retain logs for more than a few days would be enormous.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mask it entirely inside your app becuase the network connection won't work, but you can maybe use third party services like [Hola](https://hola.org/)

Comment: This isn't for Windows Phone unfortunately.

Comment: @amr i don't think you will find a "Tor substitute" already made for WinPhone. You need to make one yourself or try to hook into existing services.

Comment: lol which is exactly why I am posting this question. I know that there is no substitute. I want to make my own. The WebProxy object isn't available. I am fishing for ideas on how to recreate that functionality

Comment: @AMR as i said you would need your own servers outside the phone itself.

Comment: I think this might me the answer. This is going to take some work reconstructing though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976087/httpwebrequest-proxy-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: @AMR That's about proxy settings. Keep in mind that you also need an actual Proxy running.

Comment: Yes, my plan was to find one overseas and point everyone at the same proxy. That way any traffic coming in from that app has the same exact IP