# Windows Phone 8 get user proxy setting information

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to detect if user has added any proxy in wifi settings through C# code? if there is a way then how can i get the information like proxy address its port and remaining information in Windows Phone 8 C# app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057065/read-proxy-settings-on-wp8

Comment: But there is no webproxy class in windows phone?

Comment: No, there is no webproxy class and as I know there is no way to read proxy settings.