# Request to Proxy using Httpwebrequest on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to make a Request to proxy using HttpWebRequest Api on Windows phone 8.How to achieve this?
Any help?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/6976282/461561

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.Can I make a request using Socket?